# Reactive Extension - Observable.FromEvent typecast conversion

Tags: linq, system.reactive

I am trying to play with the reactive extension hands on lab but could not register using the FromEvent API (I am getting compile time exception). I want to receive events when the textchanged property is invoked on the text box control, can someone suggest what am i doing wrong on the conversion via FromEvent API? I some how cannot type cast or convert from TextChangeEventArgs/EventHandler to EventHandler - please show me the right way to do it. Thanks.

```
        internal delegate void TextChangedEventArgs(object sender, EventArgs e);
        var txt = new TextBox();

        var form = new Form
                      {
                          Controls = { txt }
                      };


        var subscription = Observable.FromEvent<EventHandler, TextChangedEventArgs>(
           x => (a, b) => new EventHandler(), ??????
           x => txt.TextChanged += x, 
           x => txt.TextChanged -= x
           );

       IDisposable eventSubscription = subscription.Subscribe(
           x => Console.WriteLine("Subscriber Got " + x),
           x => Console.WriteLine("An exception has occured" + x),
           () => Console.WriteLine("Action completed"));

        Console.WriteLine("in here");
       using (new CompositeDisposable(eventSubscription)) { Application.Run(form); }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
var subscription = Observable.FromEventPattern<TextChangedEventArgs>(txt, "TextChanged");
```

Comment: I found my solution in the MSDN documented `Microsoft.Phone.Reactive` namespace. The RX-Team, seems to change such things in their APIs frequenty. Thanks for your hint.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
var subscription = Observable.FromEvent(h => txt.TextChanged += h,
                                        h => txt.TextChanged -= h);
```

Comment: I am using a console based application and using Windows.Form dll/namespace, TextChangedEventHandler is a WPF Presentation delegate, is there a way i can do this with winform?

Comment: @Rohit Sharma - see my amended example for a winforms TextBox

Comment: Thanks James - I tried this before but I get compile time error 
"cannot implicitly convert type System.Action to System.EventHandler"

Comment: I've just tried this in a win forms app and it compiles fine!

Comment: Thanks for confirming but can you please share the RX core dll version number please?

Comment: Sure... I'm using 1.0.2856.0.

Comment: @Rohit Sharma - I believe that some `FromEvent` overloads have been renamed `FromEventPattern` in the latest release, so I'd recommend trying that.

Comment: Hi Richard/James, Thanks a bunch, FromEventPattern is what i actually intended to use (seems the hands on lab/documentation is not updated). Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (**edit**: if you are targeting **[Windows Phone Reactive API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff707753%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)**):

```
var subscription = Observable.FromEvent<TextChangedEventArgs>(txt, "TextChanged");
```

Comment: i do not see this overload in the latest RX library i downloaded last friday

Comment: Its renamed to FromEventPattern